# How do I reserve Debian 12 Memory for kernel and for XFCE desktop to prevent out of memory errors?

Tags: memory-usage

on debian 12

CAN NOT PREVENT terminal python program from crashing desktop

```
grub command 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash memmap=15G$10G"
sudo update-grub
```

wrote these scripts

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set XDG_SESSION_ID to 1 (default session ID)
export XDG_SESSION_ID=1

# Identify the XFCE session PID under the current user
XFCE_PID=$(ps -eo pid,cmd | grep xfce4-session | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}')

if [ -z "$XFCE_PID" ]; then
  echo "XFCE session not found. Exiting script."
  exit 1
fi
echo "XFCE session found. PID: $XFCE_PID"

# Define the cgroup name and the resource limits
CGROUP_NAME="xfce_group"
CPU_SHARES="512"  # Relative weight
MEM_LIMIT="3758096384"  # 3.5GB in bytes

# Path to the cgroup v2 hierarchy
CGROUP_PATH="/sys/fs/cgroup/$CGROUP_NAME"

# Ensure the script is running with sudo
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Please run this script with sudo."
  exit 1
fi

# Create the cgroup directory if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d "$CGROUP_PATH" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$CGROUP_PATH"
fi

# Add the XFCE session to the cgroup
echo $XFCE_PID > "$CGROUP_PATH/cgroup.procs"

# Apply CPU and memory limits
echo $CPU_SHARES > "$CGROUP_PATH/cpu.weight"
echo $MEM_LIMIT > "$CGROUP_PATH/memory.max"

echo "XFCE cgroup configuration applied successfully."
```

python programs still cause xfce to slow to a crawl and be unusable when program grabs all the memory

```
zramctl
NAME       ALGORITHM DISKSIZE  DATA  COMPR TOTAL STREAMS MOUNTPOINT
/dev/zram0 lzo-rle       5.3G  4.7G 989.4M  1.1G      16 [SWAP]
(rubix) top@top:/sda1$ sudo swapon --show
NAME           TYPE        SIZE USED  PRIO
/dev/sdb1      partition 476.9G 2.9G    -2
/dev/zram0     partition   5.3G 4.7G 32767
/sda1/swapfile file        256G   0B    -3

               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        13979036    10602360     2273768      117388     1524640     3376676
Swap:      774131700     7935264   766196436

 1950  mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/xfce_group
 1951  mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/
 1952  sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/
 1953  sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/xfce_group
 1954  echo '512' > /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/xfce_group/cpu.weight
 1955  echo '3758096384' > /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/xfce_group/memory.max
<user>  1950  mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/xfce_group
 1951  mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/
 1952  sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/
 1953  sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/xfce_group
 1954  echo '512' > /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/xfce_group/cpu.weight
 1955  echo '3758096384' > /sys/fs/cgroup/unified/xfce_group/memory.max

<username>   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/xfce_cgroup.sh
```

Comment: Your formatting looks crap, take a look at that . And I would stay away from memory reservation, that can cause more problems than it brings

Comment: Why do you have "memmap=15G$10G"? What do you expect this to do?

Answer (score 1):

`cgroups` doesn't allocate, reserve or guarantee memory for a program.

`cgroups` (control groups) are used to limit resource consumption by applications. Setting `memory.max` sets the upper bound for memory usage for programs in the cgroup, to prevent them from using more than the specified memory. If the program tries to allocate more than the limit then it gets killed by the OOM-killer.

To prevent a Python program from crashing your desktop you need to apply `cgroups` memory limits to the Python program to prevent it from allocating too much memory.

Allocating 738 GB of swap on a system with 13 GB of RAM is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

> reserve Debian 12 Memory ... to prevent out of memory errors?

That's not the way to fix the problem.

Are you talking about out of memory errors or the OOMKiller?

If a program simply cannot allocate enough memory to run then either go buy more memory or rewrite the program / use a different program.

For the OOMKiller, things are a bit more complex. If you have look around the internet you'll see lots of people talking about using oom_adj to deal with OOM scenarios. That is not the way to address the problem either.

OOMKiller events occur because the kernel promises applications more memory than is available in the system. This is by design. Usually, programs don't use all the memory they ask for. Sometimes the kernel gets this wrong.

There are 3 ways to resolve matters:

1. throw memory at the problem until it goes away. Not the most reliable approach but often useful as a quick fix. You clearly have gone completely overboard on this one and failed to solve the issue.
2. Tune the memory usage of all your executables so it stays within expected bounds. This is not really a practical solution for a workstation (as opposed to a server host).
3. Tell the kernel not to overcommit so much memory. Set the overcommit model to a static limit (vm.overcommit_memory=2) then specify how much to overcommit by in absolute or relative terms (vm.overcommit_kbytes or vm.overcommit_ratio)

Comment: The system has 738 GB of swap. Even disabling overcommit won't have any effect as `CommitLimit` includes the total swap size.

Comment: It is far from clear what issue the OP is actually trying to solve - mentions slowness, EXPLICITLY mentions crashes of desktop, the size of the swap file suggests a lot of changes. Leaving that aside, why do you think that overcommit does not take swap into consideration?

Comment: Where do I say that "overcommit does not take swap into consideration"?

Answer (score 0):

Memory reservation on Linux can be problematic because it can lead to inefficient memory usage and potentially hamper the system's ability to handle dynamic memory demands. When memory is reserved, it's essentially locked in for specific processes or purposes, which can prevent the system from reallocating it effectively based on changing requirements. This can result in wasted resources if the reserved memory isn't fully utilized by the designated process or if other processes could benefit from it. Additionally, over-reservation can lead to memory contention issues and performance degradation as the system tries to manage conflicting memory requests. Therefore, it's generally recommended to allow the Linux kernel to manage memory dynamically based on system needs rather than reserving it statically.